# android dialog opening another view behind it

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

Hi my app has 3 activities one of which is a dialog. I've done this by using this code in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

the application also has a service which can open the dialog even if the application is not visible, however when it does this it also opens one of the other activities in the background. Is there a way to stop this happening so it opens the dialog in front of the current activity (even if the activity is from a different application)?

Thanks,
ng93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up closing all my apps activities before opening the dialog activity, not ideal but seems like the only way to get the functionality im after

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding:

```
android:taskAffinity=".MyDialog"
```

to my dialog in the AndroidManifest.xml. Then it is not related to your other tasks and can be shown without bringing up the suspended activity.

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to display something in front of another application's activity.  "in front" is somewhat ambiguous, so I'll clarify in that your application can't simultaneously share the screen with another application.

The way I understand it, Android's design inherently requires that when you're doing something on-screen, your app's process/task is in the foreground and in focus, thus bringing the other activities for that task into focus.  This implies that other applications are not running with UI focus while your application is in focus.

This means that, for example, when your app launches an activity, it brings your app's stack of activities into focus and puts the new activity (in this case, your dialog box) on top of your app's stack.  The result is that if you hit 'back' while displaying the dialog, you'll go back to the activity that was previously displayed.  If the stack is cleared of previous activities, 'back' will take you to the application that was previously being displayed on screen.

There are ways of clearing the stack such as: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

---

Depending on your scenario you might want to clear the stack, or you might "exit" the app when the user closes the dialog.  Additionally, the dialog activity could override onBackPressed so that if the user hits 'back' the activity "exits" your app, returning the user to what they were doing before the dialog.

Further reading for activities and stacks: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask

Comment: i think clearing the stack is what i need to do, however FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP does not work. is there another way to clear the stack? cheers

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP works such that it will clear the activity stack above the activity receiving the intent.  Given activities A(root), B, C, and D, calling activity B with the CLEAR_TOP flag will remove C and D, making B become the top activity.  In your application, I'd assume that you're calling a NEW activity, which would result in: A, B, C, D, E(your new dialog activity).  Because there's nothing on top of E, nothing is cleared.  To clear the stack, you would call activity A with CLEAR_TOP, and have that activity fire the dialog with startActivityForResult. To be continued...

Comment: That said, what you'll then need to do in your root activity (let's keep calling it "A"), is check onActivityResult to know when your dialog activity is finished. Once you know the dialog is finished, you can call finish() on activity A, which will close your application's task and return the user to their previous application.