# When opening dialog activity, the launcher activity always shows below if in the stack

Tags: android, dialog

[image: click the lower notification to open the dialog activity]

[image: if launcher activity is in the stack it will appear below the dialog]

[image: if launcher activity is not in the stack the dialog will appear alone, which is what I want.]

I wrote a dialog activity which can be triggered when clicking a notification, like picture1. But if launcher activity is in the stack it will appear below the dialog, just like picture2. If not, the dialog activity will show alone, which is what I want, like picture3.
Could someone tell me why?

The dialog activity uses the custom style like below:

```
<style name="DialogTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And below is the notification builder code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setAutoCancel(false).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.todo_logo)).setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setContentText(getString(R.string.notificatioin_new_task)).setOngoing(true);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, DialogEventActivity.class);
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(alarmPendingIntent);
manager.notify(NEW_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I think the Activity's code is irrelevant, am I right?

Comment: @Yvette posted. Sorry for my carelessness...

Comment: but how to determine whether the launcher activity is wanted? The notification is created in a service. @Yvette

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is right here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924417/5058310

really should google more before asking questions...

Answer (score 0):

If from Activity A to Activity B,and B is a subclass of DialogActivity or its theme is set to dialog,B will display before A as a dialog,A is visible also,If your application is not in foreground and you start Activity B,it will take your whole application to foreground,carry with your all activities in your app.So your Activity B and your last visible activity when leaved your app will be visible at the same time.

So to achieve your goal,you should let your Activity B as a normal activity,not a subclass of DialogActivity,and set background of your layout for this activity to transparent and set your contentView in center of screen.

Comment: I think you can try to start B with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.

Comment: And if I set B as a normal activity, it still brings A up to the front.